# Rhino Mocks - Setting up results for non-virtual methods

Tags: .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm playing around with Rhino Mocks and am trying to set some dummy results on my mocked objects so when they are called in my factory methods I don't have to worry about the data.

But I've hit a snag, the methods I want to have the dummy results for are causing exceptions because they aren't *virtual*.

I've got code like this:

```
using(mock.Record()){
  SetupResult.For(service.SomeMethod()).Return("hello world");
}
```

Does the `SomeMethod` method have to be a virtual to be have a mocked result?

Also, what's the difference between `SetupResult.For` and `Expect.Call`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhino Mocks uses DynamicProxy2 to do it's magic, so you will not be able to set up expectations/results on non-virtual methods.

As for the difference between `SetupResult.For`, and `Expect.Call` if you want your test to fail validation if a method is not called, use `Expect.Call`.  If you just want to provide a result from your mock object, and you don't want to fail verification if it is not called, use `SetupResult.For`

So the following will fail:

```
using(mock.Record()){
    Expect.Call(service.SomeMethod()).Return("you have to run me");
}

using(mock.Replay()){
    // Some code that never calls service.SomeMethod()
}
```

And this test will not:

```
using(mock.Record()){
    SetupResult.For(service.SomeMethod()).Return("you don't have to run me");
}

using(mock.Replay()) {
    // Some code that never calls service.SomeMethod()
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, that explains it well. I was compairing Typemock and Rhino Mocks when I found this. Typemock can mock non-virtuals so it's a plus in my book so far.