# Rhino mocks : mock property to return default (null) value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino, partial-mocks

If I will use dynamic mock and try to use a property that is not set up, it will simply return default(null) for this property.

I need the same behaviour in Partial Mock only for one property. I need that this property return null. (property should be not virtual)

For example:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{ 
    public XmlDocument SomeProperty     
    {   
     get { return _someProperty ?? (_someProperty = SomeMethod()); } 
    //this getter should return null in my case and doesn't call SomeMethod
    }
}


[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var obj = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<SomeClass>();

    //Act
    obj.Act(); // this method will use SomeProperty

    //Assert
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why property shouldn't be virtual? property is syntactic sugar for getter/setter methods in C#.... (just to emphasize my point; usually `DbContext` properties in EntityFramework are virtual...). The answer to you question is you can't achieve this behaviour using only `RhinoMocks`.(unless you'll change the signature of the property to virtual)

Comment: I cannot change property, because I cover old functionality, and it will be bad practice to change access modifiers or other modifiers of existing functionality for tests.

Comment: Well your last argument isn't true; to be able to UT methods the code should be design as a testable code(you can read about it any where in SO or just google it...). I think the [chart in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31899094/4332059) might help you.

Comment: Rhino mocks can't mock non-virtual methods or properties, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342989/rhino-mocks-setting-up-results-for-non-virtual-methods